# Error updating fields in SQL Server front end application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on an application which is nearly complete except for my one page.

On the page is a gridview which is showing data from a database which works, the problem is when the user tries to update the information it is throwing out errors.

This is my code - can someone see what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this problem?

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    int Period_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    int Evo_StockLink = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

    string Evo_ItemCode = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string Evo_Description = (row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

    float UnitRate = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    float MinRate = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    float RateBeforeSevenDays  = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
    float RateAfterSevenDays = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE rates SET Period_Id = @Period_Id, Evo_StockLink = @Evo_StockLink, Evo_ItemCode = @Evo_ItemCode, Evo_Description = @Evo_Description, MinRate = @MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays = @RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays = @RateAfterSevenDays  WHERE Id = @Id"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period_Id", Period_Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_StockLink", Evo_StockLink);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_ItemCode", Evo_ItemCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evo_Description", Evo_Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitRate", UnitRate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinRate", MinRate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateBeforeSevenDays", RateBeforeSevenDays);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateAfterSevenDays", RateAfterSevenDays);

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

The error shown is :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 61:         {
>   Line 62:             GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
>   Line 63:             int Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
>   Line 64:             int Period_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
>   Line 65:             int Evo_StockLink = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

Comment: How can we help if you don't tell us what the errors are?

Comment: Also, don't use [`AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)!

Comment: When you debug this, which of the indexes on that line of code are out of range?  There are two array references there, `DataKeys[e.RowIndex]` and `Values[0]`.  One of them is out of range.  Debug and find out which one.  The code is assuming something is there when it isn't, you'll need to check if data is present before trying to use that data.

Comment: Already voted to close the question for a different reason, but also duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

In the aspx ensure you have the DataKeyNames = "Id", you also passing all the fields using Datakeys this will update the entire DB to that value.